# GeoServer - Sometimes bounding box property is missing following CQL Filter - why?

Tags: geoserver, json, cql-filter, getfeature

Usually when I run a WFS GetFeature query on GeoServer and request JSON the results conform to this format:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features": [..features here...],
"crs":{"type":"EPSG",
    "properties":{"code":"4326"}
      },
    "bbox":[0,52,0,52]

}
```

Yet I've started to find that when I run certain CQL filters on the GetFeature query, the bbox property is missing in the results.

For example:

madeupserver/geoserver/layergroup/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&maxFeatures=5000&request=GetFeature&typeName=dbossh:fullflat&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=name like '%25a%25' and owner like '%25bob smith%25'

returns the full JSON result set with the bbox, but

madeupserver/geoserver/layergroup/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&maxFeatures=5000&request=GetFeature&typeName=dbossh:fullflat&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=name like '%25ab%25' and owner like '%25bob smith%25'

(note the addition of a single letter to the name like part of the query).

returns a result set which is missing the bbox.

I'm really curious now as to why the bbox would be missing. Can anyone help me understand what the difference is that would cause GeoServer to leave out the bbox?

Comment: Which GeoServer version? Which type of datastore? Can you reproduce with some demo layer like topp:states?

Comment: @user30184 - geoserver 2.1.0 with the data coming from a PostgreSQL view with a geography column. Will try and find a suitable example.

Comment: It is pretty old version, 2.4.x is the oldest that receives bug fixes. It feels worthless to spend much time for v. 2.1.0. I would consider to install 2.6.0-RC1 which was released last Monday and try if it behaves in a similar way.